# Converting String to a BigDecimal

Tags: bigdecimal

We work with a vendor that sends us various different XML messages that we need to process.
For values such as price, sometimes they send us the number in this format - 123.45
When we run the code `BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123.45");,` it works fine

Unfortunately, they sometimes send us the number in this format - 123,45
When we run the code `BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123,45");,` we get a NumberFormatException

Does anyone know of an API that can accept a string that contains a . or a , and can convert it to a BigDecimal or will we need to do a String replace first and convert all instances of , to .?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your second point is reasonably usable. You are not provided with such a function that converts a number( actually it becomes a string when a ',' is used with it) that is not actually a number. Whereas only periods are allowed in  a float.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class.